# External headset microphone not detected, only internal is used

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, acer, microphone

I have a Realtek ALC283 sound card on an Acer Aspire V3 laptop. I tried numerous twitches to get the external microphone to show up, none of them worked. Most notably

- In `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` I tried modifying `options snd-hda-intel model=<model>` with `acer`, `alc283-headset`, `alc283-sense-combo`, `acer`, `acer-aspire`, `aspire-headset-mic` entries [found in this source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/hd-audio/models.html), one at a time, rebooting after each change.
- Installed `alsa-tools-gui` to use HDAJackRestask to override unconnected pins; done on 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, with reboot after any of those, no success: in pavucontrol Input Device section an unplugged microphone is show, but is either non responding or is still using the internal microphone. Those were the only pins with a microphone entry. Done as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1312970/headset-microphone-not-detected-by-pulse-und-alsa)

How should I proceed? Please let me know of any terminal output I should post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using an Acer Aspire and had the same issue.

You've done exactly the right steps, however try to use dell-headset-multi as your codec model instead.

I.e. adding the following to the end of your `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
```

A reboot won't hurt but to quickly try the new settings you can just reload alsa:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Now choose `Headset Microphone` in your Volume Control as  your input device.

For reference: I have only overridden the pins 0x19, 0x1a and set them to Microphone in the HDAJackRestask GUI. 
This even solved the issue that now my headphones are finally recognized automatically and I don't have to manually switch the output device!